# Идеальный способ зайти в соц. сети и использовать их функции

Tags: python, selenium

- отправки сообщений
- чтения
- перехода по ссылкам
- кликания по формам

Озадачившись проблемой, я столкнулся вот с чем: `mechanize` не видит JavaScript, поэтому по формам кликать нет возможности (+ AJAX, который разворачивает список групп-людей при поиске по критерию не проигрывается, а как следствие не виден весь список). `selenium` при сграбливании страницы выводит в непонятной кодировке "`\u0101\u243`", преобразования которой через `.encode('cp1251')` `.decode('cp1251')` и utf-8 не дают никаких результатов. + у `selenium`a вроде нет оператора прокручивания (`scroll`) бегунка, что также затрудняет вывод всего списка.

Соответственно преимуществ httplib и urllib я тоже не увидел, по той же причине, что и у mechanize - отсутствие проигрывания JS.

Буду рад любым примерам решения этой задачи, из вашей практики.

Comment: Как правило, делается два варианта. Один на ajax, второй на обычных формах. Ибо если javascript отключен (а такое часто бывает), то получается пользоваться сайтом мы не сможем.

Comment: Другими словами, предлагаете поменять параметры заголовков, в которых указываются пользуется ли браузер JS-интерпретатором, или нет(если это вообще возможно указать в запросах)?

Answer (score 1):

Селениумом можно вполне успешно скролить страницу через джаваскрипт

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

или же через имитацию нажатия пробела/пейдж даун кнопок.

В целом весь функционал что тебе нужно вполне может справится селениум.

Но предупреждаю сразу: сам по себе чистый селенум очень и очень кривой. Если же еще и нужно что бы не светилось окно браузера -- используй phantomJS в связке с селениумом.

**Но идеальным способом остается использовать API социальных сетей.**